# How to print "Nothing here" to excel if df or groupby is blank?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, xlsx

I am calculating some metrics and printing them to excel using

```
  writer = pd.ExcelWriter('File.xlxs', engine = 'xlsxwriter')
  'metric'.to_excel(writer, sheetname = 'x')
```

Sometimes my metrics will be blank (e.g. the filter has filtered everything out). Is there a way to print to excel that would let me print "Nothing here" if the metric was blank using the xlsxwriter method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the underlying xlsxwriter workbook to write custom output to the file.  More examples in the xlsxwriter [docs](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/working_with_pandas.html)

```
if metric.empty:
    sheet = writer.book.add_worksheet('y')
    sheet.write_string('A1', 'Nothing here')
```

Comment: Probably a dumb question, but If I am already defining a sheet using the writer for another metric, (e.g. Sheet X), how would I write the string to that sheet?

Comment: `sheet = writer.sheets['x']; sheet.write_string(...)`

Comment: I tried it and my df is empty but the code is printing the cols of the data frame with no data under it. Any thoughts on what to do?

Comment: I also tried the follow and am getting an error stating 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'. Any ideas?


import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[]])

if df.empty:
    print ('Empty')

import xlsxwriter
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('Blerg.xlsx', engine = 'xlsxwriter')  
  
if df.empty:
    sheet = writer.book.add_worksheet('All the things')
    sheet.write_string('a1', 'Nothing Here')

Comment: `'a1' ` should be `'A1'`

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution would be to add a conditional format to highlight cells with no data.

See the following example of using [XlsxWriter with Pandas and conditional formatting](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/example_pandas_conditional.html#ex-pandas-conditional).